# Viewing solutions of PDEs as intersection of two maps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The solution of an algebraic equation can be viewed as intersections of two maps, for example, solution of $x^2-x-1=0$ can be understood as coordinate $x$ of intersections of two functions $y=x^2$ and $y=x+1$. I was wondering if there are some techniques in partial differential equations having similar idea. In other words, if the original PDE is hard to be understood, we can analyze the intersections of two or more easier equations that consist part of the original equation.